# Qt with Python: how to route shortcuts to main menu?

Tags: python, qt, menu, pyqt5, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm a newbie with Qt, so forgive me if question is naive.

I write an application in Python using Qt widgets. The app has a main window with a menu bar. It spawns modeless dialogs which are entry forms to create/modify database records. These dialogs have no menubar (there is a single menubar in the application).

When one of the entry dialogs has focus, no menu shortcut is effective. I understand that all KeyboardEvent are handled by the active dialog, but I'd like the menu shortcut to be routed to the main window to trigger the associated action.

Presently, I must click on the main window to make it active to trigger the action.

What should I do? Reimplement the keyPressEvent() method to filter the keypresses? If so, how do I route the keypress to the main window? Is invoking ignore() enough to propagate back the event to the main window?

Comment: I think  You should provide one minimal  example so we can run and test it. Then we can fix that problem based on your code.

Comment: In Qt Designer, change the [shortcut context](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#shortcutContext-prop) of the relevant actions to [Qt.ApplicationShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ShortcutContext-enum). (NB: this will work for modeless dialogs, but not modal ones).

Comment: For the record (since the question has been closed): the solution is to set QAction shortcut context to ApplicationShortcut in Qt Designer. -- Thanks @ekhumoro and the duplicate question answer.